# JAVA AES 256 & Public Key Encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, public-key

One of our customers requires us to encrypt a message return from our web service using AES 256 & Public Key Encryption
Server Side (web service) is java based.
Client side could be java or .Net.

I'm not familiar with any of the encryption methodology and could not find any example that will get me started...

Can this even be implemented AES 256 & Public Key Encryption ?

How does it work (Public Key Encryption) ?

Please direct me to an example that will get me started.

Comment: We need you to be more precise, first AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm, as symmetric it does not work with private/public keys which is asymmetric. Or is your web-service so sensitive that it needs to be encrypted twice?

Comment: What you want is to to use SSL/TLS. In Java this is provided by the classes and APIs that make up the [JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

Comment: Normally what is used in this case is encryption with a random AES key, which in turn is encrypted with the public key delivered by the client. But as you are completely unaware of cryptography, let alone all the pitfalls, I would very much advise you to hire a professional. If you can get away with it, configure TLS as GregS proposed with a Cipher Suite that includes AES encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AES256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a specific [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) encryption scheme, which requires the communicating parties to have pre-shared an encryption key. [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) on the other hand is an asymmetric encryption principle, where each communicating party has a public key shared with every one and a private key which he keeps a secret. A typical example for the latter would be [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29).

Both symmetric and asymmetric encryption have there pros and cons, you should first figure out what you (or your client) want. Then, when implementing any cryptography always be sure to use common libraries and never (ever) try to implement any cryptography algorithms yourself. Small mistakes in these topics often lead to complete insecurity.

Comment: This is what the IT Secuirty, Risk & Compliance (ITSRC) department asked us to implement.
I have no knowledge in this area so a thought that if this is what the asked they know what they are saying …

If I understood you correctly I can not implement both AES256 and Public-key cryptography , correct ?

Comment: When using TLS/SSL both symmetric and asymmetric encryption are used (as pointed out by GregS above), maybe your department reffered to that.